# Docker: Installing NVM onto Debian image, without restarting

Tags: docker, dockerfile

Good day SO!

After installing the NVM package via:

```
RUN curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.35.3/install.sh | bash
```

The installation result message will show me something like:

```
Run the following to use nvm without restarting the terminal

export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion"
```

How do I convert this into Dockerfile syntax? Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Usually you don't.  Just start your image's Dockerfile `FROM node:14.3.0` or whatever specific version you need.  A Docker image only runs one application and its corresponding runtime, so you don't need version-manager tools.

Comment: Yes, I understand that each container should have one running app, but my usecase requires me to run multiple with supervisor managing the processes..

Answer (score 0):

I ran ENV NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm" ...
But in the end, I didn't install NVM and just directly installed node instead.